# How to get network updates from LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm working on updates of exisitng iOS app which uses LinkedIn REST API.
Earlier to get posts of user I made request to [https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{id}/network/updates?format=json](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/%7Bid%7D/network/updates?format=json)

I need to get r_network permission to accomplish that. But now with changes in API that request doesn't work. I couldn't find any useful info in [Developer Program Transition Guide](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) nor in developer docs.

Comment: I am also fetching same issue.But they don't have solution of it.I also waiting from them for more update for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the transition guide](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition), there are only 3 endpoints that are generally available:

- Profile API — `/v1/people/~`
- Share API — `/v1/people/~/shares`
- Companies API — `/v1/companies/{id}`

Your request is clearly not one of these endpoints. If you have not begun a discussion with people in the partnership program, you should start that process now.